# AppExchange Leads from Salesforce

Tags: leads, appexchange, isv, lma

Any ideas why SFDC generates Leads for Dev Org installs of an AppExchange package, but not for a Sandbox install?

Related question: Any idea if the Subscriber org type (EE, etc) can be accessed via the API? Today, we look up the Subscriber Org type by hand.

Comment: You may get better responses to your second question if you post it as a separate question. They may be related, but when you look at the title the users may not realize you will have that question in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your first question:

We have configured our AppExchange listings to receive a new lead on install regardless of the type of org. This is just a matter of adjusting settings on the Leads tab of the publishing console in AppExchange and associating a Campaign record with the "Send me leads on install" line. Combined with a lead assignment rule we get an email for each lead generated via trial or test drive (we've embedded demo video and therefore do not receive leads on demo anymore).

You are correct that the LMA does not create a license record for Sandbox installs, although you can still look up the install by org name in the Subscribers tab (I assume that's part of the manual process you mentioned). I've asked both AppExchange PM and other Salesforce personnel about this, since without a manual lookup in Subscribers tab it's not possible to distinguish between a successful install to a sandbox and a failed install to production (and therefore a customer who needs attention).

The answer I received from AppExchange PM was "this is a known issue. no info on whether it will be addressed." Not very helpful, but at least they know it's an issue.

Other Salesforce sources gave me some additional detail that I think is worth sharing. The LMA is trying to be smart about issuing licenses. Part of being smart is deciding which installs represent potentially paid customers. In the case of a sandbox install, the LMA interprets that install as having no possibility of being a paid license, and therefore does not create a license record. This also means that sandbox trials never expire.

A Dev org, however, is seen as a potentially paid install and therefore a license record is created and the trial expiration will be automatically enforced.

Once I knew this, we adjusted our follow-up actions with trial customers to better address the type of org their trial went to.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Its also frustrating that we have no easy way to see the Orgs that have given access for dev support; and that Subscribers cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation doesn't clearly state "why not" (and this is a *very common* scenario with the documentation) in regards to leads and Sandbox installs, but I'd take an educated guess and say that Sandbox installs would most likely duplicate leads from one of the other four sources (production installs, test drives, demos, or trials), and are therefore too much "noise." This question is best directed at the Partner Program people instead of a general forum. If you find out, please feel free to update this answer.

In regards to the latter question, the answer is, no, you cannot query subscribers. This was discovered through a process of experimentation. I first examined the global describe objects, and found nothing in my LMA org that would describe a subscriber. Next, I took a look at the subscribers tab and noted that it is a Visualforce-type page (i.e. it doesn't expose a key prefix). Finally, I took a look at the links for each subscriber, and I found an unusual ID value with a key prefix of 033. I first tried to visit it as a regular record (x.salesforce.com/033...), and I received an error 'Invalid Organization'.

In short, this page uses a sort of 'without sharing' controller to access an ID value that we don't have access to directly. This object is called AllPackage (found through `System.debug(((Id)'033...').getSObjectType())`, which can't be described, queried, or even accessed outside the subscribing organization.